# Exported Firebase .ref() objects have no .on() method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my React app I am initializing my firebase object with its db references in its own file and then exporting that out using a higher order component later down the line:

```
class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    app.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    this.auth = app.auth();
    this.db = app.database();
    console.log(this.auth)
  }

 .
 .
 .

 user = uid => this.db.ref(`user/${uid}`);

 users = () => this.db.ref('users');

 project = pid => this.db.ref(`project/${pid}`);

 projects = () => this.db.ref('projects');
}

export default Firebase;
```

Writing to the database is no problem, but when I am trying to read data and I go to call .on() on my initialized db refs I find they are not a function?

```
const ProjectPage = props => {
    const ref = props.firebase.project;
    ref.on("value", snap => {
        console.log(snap);
    })
    return (
        .....
    )
}

export default withFirebase(ProjectPage);
```

What is really confusing me is that if I initialize a ref in the component it **does** appear to have the correct methods :

```
    const ref = props.firebase.db.ref('thisworksfine');
    ref.on("value", snap => {
        console.log(snap);
    })
```

This is my first time asking a question on here but I am so stumped by this. Why are the correct methods attached when initializing in the component file but not in a separate one, surely they are referencing exactly the same type of object?

Any help would be really appreciated, thank you for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database references are functions so you should call them like:

```
const ref = props.firebase.project();
```

now you can access ref properties and methods.

*This is just a reference to your actual function, not the value returned in that function:*

```
const ref = props.firebase.project
```

Comment: Thank you so much haha... I had a feeling it was something simple like that but I just couldn't spot it